# Name of YA fantasy book, post apocalyptic setting in a gray/sunless world

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

This has been bothering me for years, I never can seem to find this fantasy YA book I read as a teenage. What I remember is that the protagonist is a young girl living in a medieval/post apocalyptic setting. She finds out she is special in some way, can somehow help her world have sunlight again or be less gloomy. There's an older woman, a witch/sorceress who wants her dead. There's also something about a powerful, magical amulet/necklace.

The young girl is a reluctant hero, she goes on a long journey. The book is older, from the 90s maybe even 80s. I thought for the longest time it was by a New Zealand female writer but I'm not sure about that.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Winter of Fire by Sherryl Jordan, perhaps. 1992, NZ author.

Comment: Thank you, Winter of Fire is most likely it, though there's less fantasy in it than what I'm remembering. I think I'm mixing up another book's plot with this book.

Comment: That does happen. I'm not sure that the amulet/sorceress is part of this book.

Comment: There is also [_The Curse of the Mistwraith_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janny_Wurts) about a world without sun (because of an eternal fog) by a female writer. Fantasy, witches, medieval setting, long journey, check...

Comment: @Frock: You can always write that up as an answer so that it can be accepted, or at least voted up so that future querents might find it. :)